# Menu Item onClickListener for fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, fragment

I have the following menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_heart_outline_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Favorite" />
</menu>
```

How would I set an onClick listener for this? bearing in mind that my class extends Fragment:

```
public class My_Profile extends Fragment implements ....{}
```

...and I do not know if this makes any difference but I have already inflated a layout in this java file too.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testFragment, container, false);
...
}
```

**Update 1**

This is what I tried after the suggestions but nothing seems to happen can someone please tell me what im doing wrong:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menu_share) {
            Log.d("ButtonClick", "button click worked");
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and in the onCreate added this:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

**Update 2**

Dont know if this makes any difference, I'm just working with an example at the moment and the menu is also inflated like this. I dont know if that affects the other 2 methods:

```
 mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
```

**update 3**

This is now what I have tried yet, still the button click doesn't log anything:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testFragment, container, false);

        ...

        return myView;
        }
```

and just for testing redirected to one of my other Activities, yet nothing still happens:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menu_share) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }else{
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),SignupActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
```

Comment: can anyone help? no solutions worked so far

Answer (score 1):

Your fragment should have these two methods to handle the menu: `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` with the onClick stuff in the latter.

For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //TODO
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_share) {
        //TODO
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

EDIT

Don't forget `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` for your fragment *(thanks)*

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in the `onCreate` or `onCreateView` function of the fragment.

Comment: @lionscribe i used Google and found the setHasOptionsMenu attribute, however still doesn't do anything.

Comment: You also have to overwrite `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, and inflate a menu. You then handle the menu in `onOptionsItemSelected`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you have a good code.
All you need to do is re-arrange the `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)`

For instance:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.testFragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think that you don't need to call `mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);` since the menu has been inflated `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`

Answer (score 0):

@BadCodersHub i have tried your scenario and its working fine with following code.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return myView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Log.d("","action Settings Clicked !!");
            break;
        case R.id.menu_share:
            Log.d("","action menu_share Clicked !!");
            break;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Hope this will help you.you need to override onCreateOptionMenu and onOptionItemSelected methods

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work nothing logs when clicking a button. I do inflate the menu to the toolbar in the onCreate too otherwise I don't see the menu       mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);  Would this make a difference